# How to use external typescript libraries on client side?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I've followed this guide: [How to compile Typescript into a single file with amd modules with gulp](https://westerndevs.com/TypeScript-with-AMD-and-Gulp/).

App.ts

```
import { CreateModel } from "./Models/CreateModel";
import { CreateView } from "./Views/CreateView";
import { CreateController } from "./Controllers/CreateController";

export class App {
    public init() {
        const model = new CreateModel();
        const view = new CreateView(model);
        const controller = new CreateController(model, view);
    }
}
```

CreateController.ts

```
export class CreateController {
    private model: CreateModel;
    private view: CreateView;

    constructor(model: CreateModel, view: CreateView) {
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;

        this.init();
    }    

    more code...
}
```

CreateView.ts

```
import { CreateModel } from "../Models/CreateModel";

export class CreateView {
    private model: CreateModel;

    constructor(model: CreateModel) {
        this.model = model;

        this.init();
    }    

    more code...
}
```

CreateModel.ts

```
export class CreateModel {
    more code...
}
```

index.html

```
<script src="~/Scripts/config.js"></script>
<script data-main="main" src="~/Scripts/require.js"></script>
```

config.js

```
var require = {
    baseUrl: "../../Scripts/",
    paths: {
        'App': 'app'
    }
};
```

main.js

```
requirejs(['App'], function (MyApp) {
    var app = new MyApp.App();
    app.init();
});
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [ "es2017", "dom" ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "outFile": "./Scripts/app.js",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "files": [
    "Scripts/Typescripts/App.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./Scripts/Typescripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

This works fine and everything compiles into ~/Scripts/app.js. Now I want to add an external library to this. It's [ts.validator.fluent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts.validator.fluent) and it's on npm. How can I use this on the client side?

I've tried to download the files from Github, put it in a separate folder and then import:

CreateController.ts

```
import { IValidator, Validator, ValidationResult } from './Plugins/ts.validator.fluent';
export class CreateController {
    ...
    private checkEmail(validateVm: ValidateVm) {

        let validationResult = new Validator(validateVm.value).Validate(ValidateRules.email);

    ...
    }
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught Error: Script error for "Plugins/ts.validator.fluent", needed by: Controllers/CreateController
```

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to use npm dependencies in client-side code would probably be to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/).

Webpack can take your JS files, resolve the imports, and then create a single bundle that include all the code you depend on (similar to what you're doing with creating a single `app.js` JavaScript file. When webpack sees an import that resolves to an npm module, it will automatically include that code too.

*Note: you need to be careful to only use NPM packages that are designed to be used in the client-side, and don't depend on the Node.js environment. Many packages are designed to only be used on the server-side, and depend on node libraries etc...*

Using require at this point would likely become unnecessary, and make things more complicated, as webpack's automated bundling will do a similar thing, additionally, exporting all the code as a single typescript file may complicate things.

I would recommend the following build process:

1. Compile all typescript code, and export to a temporary directory (e.g. `.tmp`)
2. Use webpack to process the `.js` files in `.tmp`, specifying the `main` entry point.

For something like this, it may be a good idea to start using a build system like [gulp](https://gulpjs.com/), rather than having separate commands that you need to run to build your project. You could also use the `"scripts"` property in `package.json` to write your build commands so you don't find yourself having to run many different commands manually.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following Sam Lanning's answer and now it works!

folder structure

```
├── Scripts
|   ├── Ts-build
|   ├── Typescripts
|       ├── Subfolders
|       App.ts
|   App.js
└── index.html
tsconfig.json
webpack.config.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "ts.validator.fluent": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.30",
    "@types/node": "^12.6.9",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: './Scripts/Ts-build/App',
    mode: 'development',
    target: 'web',
    watch: true,

    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts')
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js)?$/,
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, './Scripts/Ts-build/'),
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            enforce: "pre",
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: "source-map-loader"
        }]
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: [".webpack.js", ".web.js", ".js"]
    },

    externals: {
        // require("jquery") is external and available
        //  on the global var jQuery
        "jquery": "jQuery"
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
};
```